# How to get Input date presentation format in html5 or get current OS display date format in Angular/Typescript?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date

Friends,

The Input control of HTML5 displays date format as OS date format(ex: 05 Jul-2020)  but wire format is always YYYY-MM-DD.  When i show the error message, i would like to show the date format that Input control shows.

Example:

1. Current OS date format is DD-MMM-YYYY ( 05-Jul-2020)
2. So the input control also shows in same format which is DD-MMM-YYYY.

[image]

3. When user choose wrong date ( may be past date ), i want to throw error message in the same format but at the same time i don't want to hardcode this format as it might change as per user's operating system and regions.

   Sample error messsage is 'Please select date after 05-Jul-2020'

I tried following methods to get the OS / Input presentation date format but nothing worked as expected.

1. getLocaleDateFormat("en-US", FormatWidth.Short)  - Returns m/d/yy
2. toLocaleString() - returns YYYY-MM-DD

I am expecting a solution that should work in all the operating systems ( Windows, Mac, Linux ).  Please guide me on the right solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="date" name="begin" 
    placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy" value=""
    min="1997-01-01" max="2030-12-31">
```